# Toggle divs and highlight menu item for current

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle several divs on/off depending on the menu item clicked. Also I want to add the class "active" to the current menu item link.

At the moment, the divs toggle on/off depending on the menu item clicked but all the menu items become "active" on click.

Also, when the page first loads, all divs except "synopsis" are hidden, so I want to show that's the one that's active.

My jquery isn't the best so this is probably a long winded way of doing it but here's what I've tried:

Here's the menu:

```
<a class="first-panel-menu synopsis-link" href="#">Synopsis</a> |
<a class="director-link" href="#">Director</a> |
<a class="cast-link" href="#">Cast</a> |
<a class="details-link" href="#">Details</a> |
```

Here's the divs I want to show/hide:

```
<div class="synopsis">
    <h3>Synopsis</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="director">
    <h3>Director</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>                          

<div class="cast">
    <h3>Cast</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="details">
    <h3>Details</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>
```

And the jquery:

```
// Individual film links        
$( ".synopsis-link" ).click(function(e) {
    $( ".director" ).hide();
    $( ".cast" ).hide();
    $( ".details" ).hide();         
    $( ".synopsis" ).toggle( function() {});
    $(".synopsis-link").toggleClass('active non-active');
    e.preventDefault();   
});

$( ".director-link" ).click(function(e) {
    $( ".synopsis" ).hide();
    $( ".cast" ).hide();
    $( ".details" ).hide(); 
    $( ".director" ).toggle( function() {});
    $(".director-link").toggleClass('active non-active');
    e.preventDefault();   
});

$( ".cast-link" ).click(function(e) {
    $( ".synopsis" ).hide();
    $( ".director" ).hide();
    $( ".details" ).hide();
    $( ".cast" ).toggle( function() {});
    $(".cast-link").toggleClass('active non-active');   
    e.preventDefault();   
}); 

$( ".details-link" ).click(function(e) {
    $( ".synopsis" ).hide();
    $( ".cast" ).hide();
    $( ".director" ).hide();
    $( ".details" ).toggle( function() {});
    $(".details-link").toggleClass('active non-active');        
    e.preventDefault();   
});
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add some generic classes, you can target the menu link's click using `$(this)` instead of writing the same code for all the links

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".section").hide();   // initially hides all sections 
    $(".synopsis").show();  // initially shows synopsis section
    $(".section-link[section='synopsis']").addClass('active');  
                            // initially adds active class to synopsis link
    $('.section-link').click(function() {
        var section = $(this).attr('section'); // identifies link that was clicked
        $(".section").hide();   // hides all other sections     
        $("." + section).show(); // shows chosen section
        $(".section-link").removeClass('active'); // removes active from all other links
        $(this).addClass('active'); // adds active to link clicked
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
a.active:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="first-panel-menu section-link" section="synopsis" href="#">Synopsis</a> |
<a class="section-link" section="director" href="#">Director</a> |
<a class=" section-link" section="cast" href="#">Cast</a> |
<a class="section-link" section="details" href="#">Details</a> 
<br/><br/>
<div class="synopsis section">
    <h3>Synopsis</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        SYNOPSIS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="director section">
    <h3>Director</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        DIRECTOR Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>                          

<div class="cast section">
    <h3>Cast</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        CAST Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="details section">
    <h3>Details</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        DETAILS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change the behaviour to a generic function and the code looks better. It's changing the classname to a dataset.

### Menu:

```
 <div id="menu">
    <a class="first-panel-menu" data-box-target="synopsis" href="#">Synopsis</a> |
    <a data-box-target="director" href="#">Director</a> | 
    <a data-box-target="cast" href="#">Cast</a> |
    <a data-box-target="details" href="#">Details</a> | 
 </div>
```

### Boxes

```
<div data-box="synopsis">
    <h3>Synopsis</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>

<div data-box="director">
    <h3>Director</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>                          

<div data-box="cast">
    <h3>Cast</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>

<div data-box="details">
    <h3>Details</h3>
    <p class="panel-main-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices aliquam tellus, sit amet vehicula ante lacinia a. Vivamus quis elementum risus. Mauris dictum, dolor nec ornare scelerisque, metus augue condimentum sapien, dignissim aliquet mauris ipsum quis arcu.
    </p>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#menu > a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var boxtarget = $(this).dataset().boxTarget;
   $('div[data-box]').hide(); // hide all
   $('div[data-box="'+boxtarget+'"]').show(); // show only what you need
   $(this).toggleClass("active"); // toggle class in menu
});
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Some qlues on your jQuery code:

1. instead of `.toggle( function() {});` (why ever use empty callback?) use `show()`,
2. combine all element in single selector (you can also introduce new class) and call `.hide()` only once,
3. instead of toggleClass use addClass on current element, but firstly remove that class from previous element.

Here is code exemple for one link (

```
$(".synopsis-link").click(function(e) {
    $(".director,.cast,.details").hide();        
    $(".synopsis").show();
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(".synopsis-link").addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();   
});
```

in fact with some tweaking one could make only one universal function, but with change in html first (id instead of class):

```
<a id="synopsis-link" class="first-panel-menu" href="#">Synopsis</a> |
<a id="director-link" href="#">Director</a> |
<a id="cast-link" href="#">Cast</a> |
<a id="details-link" href="#">Details</a> |
```

here is universal function:

```
$("#synopsis-link,#cast-link,#details-link").click(function(e) {
    $(".synopsis,.director,.cast,.details").hide();        
    $("."+e.currentTarget.id.replace('-link','')).show();
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();   
});
```